# In Maven, how to compile a class outside the source directory into an arbitrary target directory?

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I have a legacy app that I'm porting from Ant to Maven.  My Maven build works fine for the main project, which I've moved into the standard Maven directory layout (`*.java` files in `/src/main/java/`) and it outputs the compiled classes into `/target/classes/` as neat as you could wish.  These are packaged in a `.war` file.

However, the project also has a class outside of the folder hierarchy, indeed outside of the web application, that contains scripts that run via cron job.  Let's say it's `/cronjobs/MyClass.java`.  I need that class to be compiled and output to `/target/cronjobs/MyClass.class` and zipped up as part of the resulting `.war` file, in its `/cronjobs/` folder.

Can Maven do this?  I know it's possible to change the default "src" directory and "target" directory, but I don't know if (or how) it's possible to run a separate, parallel compile step for just one class.

I can move the source file, of course, if it's easier to compile it with the other classes and then move it later (maybe with the WAR plugin?) but I definitely need the compiled `MyClass.class` file in the `/cronjobs/` directory of the `.war`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the project in 2 parts, webapp as war and cronjobs as jar. Maven knows about multi-module format and it is somewhat the best way to go forward and decouple the webapp from non-webapp code.

Comment: Does that mean two different POM files?

Comment: Yes, and eventually a parent POM with a `<modules>` section where you can specify the 2 of them for a convenient way of building the projects. At work, we have a parent POM with about 10 sub-modules and whenever I want to build all of them, I just `mvn clean package` in the parent pom directory.